# Eclipse with TFS plugin - project missing in project selection

Tags: eclipse, tfs

My Eclipse suddenly facing some problem when start up:

[image]

And the project that I want to connect in TFS server is missing in Project Selection: (not the two I erase in the image, is the third one)

[image]

I am sure I have the access to the project as my Microsoft Visual Studio which connect to same project is working fine.

Does anyone have idea how to solve it?

Comment: Have you ever changed your Machine name before?  Are there any unsupporeted characters in the workspace path or Machine name? If yes, try to remove them, then remap.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have checked my workspace path and Machine name, both don't have any unsupported characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andy-MSFT, thanks a lot for your support so far. My colleague have solve the problem by doing few steps:

1. Remove all the workspace in Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Startup And Shutdown -> workspace

   [image]
2. Untick in Windows -> Preferences -> Team Foundation Server

   [image]
3. Click use different Credentials and re-login your account:

   [image]

The project now appears in the project selection and it is working fine.

Thanks again for the support @Andy-MSFT.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Check if there are any unsupported characters in your machine name
  and workspce path. If it it, jsut remove them eg "`My-PC`" update to
  "`MyPC`"
- Remove the TFS server first from TEE, then re-add it again.
- Unintall the TFS plugin (TEE), clean caches, then [reinstall the TFS
  plugin](https://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/eclipse), add and connect to the TFS server to check that again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my Machine name don't have any unsupported characters. I have tried to re-install both Eclipse and TFS plugin, i still get the same error.

Comment: @AldenKen Which version of Eclipse do you use? I checked at my side (`Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)`), it works correctly. What about other clients? you can try to install the Eclipse and the TEE in another clean machine to check if that works for you.

Comment: My Eclipse is 3.7, one of my colleague facing the same issue and other people is working fine, my Eclipse is setting up on a VDI, i have tried set up on other VDI, the other one is working fine.